# Check box with ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, onclicklistener, background-color

so I have a `ListView` with item that when I click on one of the itens it bring me to a edit page with 3 check boxes.
I want to do that whenever I check one of the `CheckBox` all the other check boxes will be unchecked and the 3 checkbox will have `Listview.backgroundcolor` on a specific item that I chose.
I want check box that will make the background green
the other one will be yellow and the third will be red.
and after i click on save button the color will be saved

```
        final CheckBox greenceck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.greencheck);
        final CheckBox yellowceck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yellowcheck);
        final CheckBox redceck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.redcheck);

        greenceck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                yellowceck.setChecked(false);
                redceck.setChecked(false);
                greenceck.setChecked(true);
                Vans.listView.getItemAtPosition(Color.GREEN);
                notify();
            }
        });

yellowceck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        redceck.setChecked(false);
        greenceck.setChecked(false);

        yellowceck.setChecked(true);
        Vans.listView.getItemAtPosition(Color.YELLOW);
        notify();


    }
});

        redceck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                yellowceck.setChecked(false);
                greenceck.setChecked(false);
                redceck.setChecked(true);


                Vans.listView.getItemAtPosition(Color.RED);
                notify();



            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem are ?

Comment: it dosn't make the list item background in color when i choose the check box